# Run dot net assembily with network on linux (Raspberry Pi) with mono

Tags: raspberry-pi, mono

I have installed mono on a raspberry pi and it works for some things but for Honeygain https://dashboard.honeygain.com/ it does not work the installer does not run so I installed it on a windows computer then copied the files to a raspberry pi but when I run the .exe it loads the login screen and when I log in it gives the error "There seems to be a problem with your Network Connection" is there something else I need to do to enable networking?

the output of "file Honeygain.exe":
Honeygain.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows